# Перевод большого числа в byte

Tags: java, byte

Делаю шифрование с помощью сдвигов битов в байте.Но если байту присвоить значение больше 127, оно начинает терять данные.Как правильно перевести большое число в байты без потери данных или чтобы его можно было потом восстановить?

Comment: Никак. Если коротко. Нельзя впихнуть невпихуемое. Так что, нужно большое число разбивать на байты. Для одной переменной int нужно будет 4 переменных byte

Comment: Привидите пример того что вы делаете, какой результат получаете и каой результат хотелось бы получить.

Comment: Можно для этого использовать массив

Comment: Чтобы не терять биты при сдвигах, сдвигать надо циклически.

Answer (score 2):

В Java нет беззнаковых типов, но если вы хотите - можете сымитировать беззнаковый байт `uint8` (хранит значения 0...255), вычитая 256 из чисел больше 127. Так вы будите использовать отрицательную область -128...-1.

Обратное преобразование `int b = Byte.toUnsignedInt(a);`

Это будет работать для чисел до 255. Больше чем 256 значений в один байт положить не получиться.

Чтобы перевести в байты числа больших размеров берите байты от типов `short` - 2 байта, `int` - 4 байта, или `long` - 8 байт. Отдельные байты можно получить методом битового сдвига.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю для этих целей можно использовать BigInteger. Не думаю, что это оптимальный метод. В java вроде был api для шифрования и есть сторонние библиотеки. BigInteger можно перевести в массив байта путем вызова toByteArray(). Если есть знания английского или гугл переводчика https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html
В дополнение комментария о сдвигах. В стандартной библиотеке нет циклических сдвигов для Byte. Но можно их реализовать на примере сдвигов для Integer из openjdk. rotateLeft и rotateRight методы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]